# Как из firebase выводить картинку которая храниться как ссылка?

Tags: android, android-fragment, firebase

Вывожу информацию с firebase о пользователе, все что связано с текстом я вывел а вот как вывести картинку пользователя я не понимаю. У меня есть Storage там есть нужная мне картинка, в самой Realtime Database у меня храниться ссылка на эту картинку. Как благодаря этой ссылке вывести картинку?
Вот тут в фрагменте я работаю с RecyclerView

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
reference = database.getReference("Users");

```
    result = new ArrayList<>();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,container,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerUsers);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()); //возможно ошибка
    llm.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    adapter = new UserAdapter(result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateList();

    return rootView;
```

А вот моя модель конструктора которая просто возвращает мне логин пользователя с Firebase.А вот как вывести картинку по юрл в этом конструкторе я понять и не могу...

```
public String login;
public UserModel(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например использовать [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/) (или Picasso, или Glide).

Coil:

```kotlin
imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
```

Picasso:

```kotlin
Picasso.get()
    .load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
    .into(imageView)
```

Glide:

```kotlin
Glide.with(context)
    .load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
    .into(imageView)
```

Или так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

Изменить модель, добавить ссылку:

```java
public String login;
public String avatarUri;
public UserModel(String login, String avatarUri) {
    this.login = login;
    this.avatarUri = avatarUri;
}
```

Структурна в БД должна быть такой, чтобы ссылку можно было привязать к конкретному пользователю. В итоге Вы получаете объект с логином и ссылкой на аватар. В Адаптере, там где Вы выводите логин, добавляете код Picasso со ссылкой `UserModel.getAvatarUri()`.

Comment: Дело в том, что через Picasso я уже выводил изображение в профиль настроек пользователя, где он мог указать свой ник и свое фото.А тут я хочу вывести изображение для RecycleView, так как хочу ленту пользователей с их фото и никами.И для этих целей я создал конструктор которые возвращает мне только логин пользователя, а вот как реализовать через конструктор вывод фото по юрл использую тот же Picasso в мою дурню голову не приходит ответ.Если вам не сложно, можете подсказать как через конструктор вывести.

Comment: @DenissZadorozhniy Нужно видеть код, без кода тяжело ответить.

Comment: Спасибо, вот добавил код.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за вашу помощь. Понял теперь идею вывода картинки в RecyclerView.Cделал все как вы написали.Изменил модель, добавил строчку Picasso.get().load(user.avatarUri).into(holder.userImage); Программа запустилась, но картинки почему то так и не вывела.

Comment: Все решил проблему. Я изначально не знал что переменные которые я создаю в конструкторе должны точно так же называться как и переменные в Firebase. после исправления все заработало и вывело картинку. Спасибо, вам еще раз за помощь, без вас я бы еще долго думал как решить эту проблему.